# Correct way for writing domain of a function

Tags: notation

When writing the domain of a function, in set builder notation, how does one correctly write the set of all real numbers?  E.g. for $f(x) = 3x+2$, which of the following would correctly state the domain?  Are they all OK, just some better than others, or are some incorrect?

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}\},
 \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}, \qquad\text{or}\qquad
\{x | x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just write "all of $\mathbb{R}$" in the brackets, or perhaps just what you wrote in the first two. The last one seems inelegant. Also $1$ and $2$ are equivalent: you can write them with or without the brackets.

Comment: @scoopfaze The first and second notations are *not* equivalent.  The first specifies a set (though somewhat ambiguously), while the second specifies an element of a set.  They don't mean the same thing---the addition or subtraction of braces is important.  See, for example, the distinction between $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$.  The first is the emptyset.  The second is a set which contains one element.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made what I was saying clearer: I meant that $\{\text{all of }\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\text{all of }\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent. You're right that, as written they are not the same. I was stipulating that he write out the "all of R", and then they would be the same.

Comment: @scoopfaze I would still object; the set $\{\text{all of $\mathbb{R}$}\}$ is a set containing one element, while "all of $\mathbb{R}$" is the set of real numbers. The braces have genuine meaning.  If it is necessary to somehow typographically set the specification of the set apart, perhaps parentheses?  e.g. $(\text{all of $\mathbb{R}$})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of a function is a set, thus whatever notation you use, it should specify some set.  Beyond that, there are some conventions about *how* one specifies a set, or how one might want to specify a particular set under a specific set of instructions, but these conventions often come down to a matter of taste rather than anything deeply mathematical.  Examining the proposed notations:

1. The notation $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is a little ambiguous, but would probably be understood.  As Eike Schulte points out, there is something missing—either the "selection criterion" which tells you how you are choosing element of $\mathbb{R}$, or you are specifying the name and domain of some variable which will be acted on by some selection criterion.  That is, the notation does not tell us if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is the selection criterion, or if it is just naming a real variable which is going to be acted on by some selection.  More generally, set builder notation typically has the following form:
   $$ \{ \text{variable specification} \mid \text{selection criterion} \}. $$
   For example,
   $$ \{ x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x \ge 47 \}
   \qquad\text{or}\qquad
   \{ x\in \mathbb{C} \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}. $$
   In the first example, a variable is specified (we are going to build a set of of real numbers, which we will call $x$ for the sake of selecting particular element of $\mathbb{R}$), and then acted upon by some selection criterion (we only consider values of $x$ which are greater than or equal to $47$).

   That being said, authors will often shorten their notation if there is little danger of ambiguity.  For example, in my own work, I often use the notation
   $ \{ \Re(s) > D \}, $
   which is shorthand for
   $$ \{s\in\mathbb{C} : \Re(s) > D \}, $$
   where $\Re(s)$ denotes the real part of a complex number $s$.  In context, this notation is perfectly clear.  On the other hand, it is potentially ambiguous in other settings.
2. The notation $x\in\mathbb{R}$ does not specify a set.  Instead, it specifies an element of a set.  This notation is read "$x$ is an element of the set $\mathbb{R}$".  It is possible that this could be written into a sentence to specify the domain of a function, e.g. "The domain of $f$ is all $x$ such that $x\in\mathbb{R}$."  However, this sentence is somewhat clunky.
3. Of the options presented, $\{ x \mid x\in\mathbb{R} \}$ is the best.  It specifies a set (rather than an element of a set) in a completely unambiguous manner.  On the other hand, it is kind of redundant, since
   $$ \{x \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \} = \mathbb{R}. $$
   Instead of writing this in set builder notation, one could just write the name of the set (i.e. $\mathbb{R}$).

**A Small Typographical Note:**  The vertical bar used in set builder notation should have a little bit of space around it.  Rather than typing `|`, you might consider using `\mid`.  For use with large braces, `\,\middle|\,` also works:
$$\left\{ \frac{x}{y} \,\middle|\, x\in \mathbb{Z}, y\in\mathbb{N} \right\}. $$
Finally, you could also use a colon:  $\{ x\in\mathbb{R} : x \ge 47\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of your function $f$ is simply $\mathbb{R}$. Your third set, $\{ x | x \in \mathbb{R} \}$, is just a convoluted way of writing it, so it would be technically correct (but simply writing $\mathbb R$ is better).

The first one, $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \}$, is not really set-builder notation, because you are missing the “selection” part and a set of the form $\{ a_1, \dots, a_n \}$ without a vertical bar is usually understood as listing all the elements of the set. People will probably understand what you mean, but again, writing $\mathbb{R}$ alone is shorter and clearer.

The second option is not a set but an assertion about $x$, so it is not directly an answer to the question “What is the domain of $f$?” That might be okay though, for example writing “The function defined by $f(x) = 3x + 2$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$” is absolutely acceptable. Other options include:$$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb R, \quad f(x) = 3x + 2$$ or $$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \quad x \mapsto 3x + 2.$$
In both of these, the first $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ specifies the domain as $\mathbb R$ and second specifies the codomain (also $\mathbb R$ is this case).

Answer (score 0):

Mostly used notation for writing your function is
"Let $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=3x+2$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$".